# Error stacktrace points to wrong line - Node.js + Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, minify, stack-trace

I'm using Webpack to minify Node.js code into one bundle. The problem appears when an error is thrown. Wrong lines are shown in error's stacktrace.

For example here's screenshot of my code where error is happening in unminified version of the file:
[image]

And here's the stacktrace of the error when running the minified bundle:

```
[16:20:20] - ERROR - http://localhost:3000/generate/error-abc/
TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
    at eo.get (/Users/dmitri/website/dist/app.js:1:61951)
```

If I go to the minified bundle file to this specific line I can see that it's slightly after actual error:
[image]

This is how my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  target: 'node',
  optimization: {
    nodeEnv: false
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  entry: './server/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [['latest-node', { target: '8', modules: false }]]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new SentryWebpackPlugin({
       release: process.env.SENTRY_RELEASE,
       include: './dist',
       setCommits: {
         repo: 'org/website',
         auto: true
       },
       configFile: 'sentry.properties'
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map'
};

module.exports = env => {
  if (env === 'develop') {
    config.mode = 'development';
    config.watch = true;
    config.plugins.push(
      new NodemonPlugin({
        nodeArgs: ['--inspect']
      })
    );
  }

  if (env === 'production') {
    config.mode = 'production';
    config.watch = false;
  }

  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __DEV__: JSON.stringify(env === 'develop'),
      __PRODUCTION__: JSON.stringify(env === 'production')
    })
  );

  return config;
};
```

You might ask why I'm interested in it. The answer is that because of the wrong line reported in Node.js stacktrace, Sentry displays wrong code in error preview window. Here's how the frame looks in Sentry using debug mode:

```
frame { colno: 60951,
  filename: '/Users/dmitri/website/dist/app.js',
  function: 'eo.get',
  lineno: 1,
  in_app: true,
  module: 'app',
  pre_context: [],
  context_line: '\'{snip} ),eo.get("/api/cache/",$r()),eo.post("/api/cache/",$r()) {snip}',
  post_context: [ '//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map' ] }
```

Could anyone please say me if it's a correct behavior or something is wrong with my Webpack configuration? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour because of `webkpack` behaviour which is creating bundle file which is compressed,  what you need is mapping the source code, using source maps  , and we use it only in the development stage , but `sentry` offer for you a plugin for `webpack` so you can follow up your errors  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/webpack-plugin

Comment: I'm using Sentry webpack plugin and as you can see in my webpack config I'm using a `source-map` as devtool. Unfortunately Sentry maps errors to wrong lines. That's why I'm suspecting the stacktrace at first glance.

Comment: but as I see , you didn't Implement the Sentry webpack plugin 
 this is an example by `Sentry` , 
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin/blob/9c4592c6d0fd56b827bbef1aca76b9b4e0cd8018/example/webpack.config.js